# JBoss cli connect to docker

Tags: docker, jboss, jboss-cli

i have transfer my files to host machine. I already bring up jboss docker. How can i deploy the war file in my host mchine to container via cli. Please dvice. I not planning to use custom image

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the management port from docker -p9990:9990.
Also I'm not sure to what address the management is bound to. You would have to pass -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 to the command line.